# ADO .NET Data Services for dummies

Tags: ado.net, wcf-data-services

I'm taking another project currently, which is based on the ADO .NET DS, and I need to get into the topic as quick as possible.

What is the purpose of ADO .NET Data Services in simple words? What is the best resource explaining ADO .NET Data Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The microsoft page on the topic has a fairly good summary -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx

This site also has a good intro

http://greggalipeau.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/introduction-to-adonet-data-services-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

REST style web services for data access.  By REST style, that means using HTTP GET/PUT/DELETE/POST instead of SQL DML, and for returning results it uses JSON and Atom Pub (an xml format kind-of similar to RSS) instead of a binary result structure and protocol like Microsoft SQL Servers TDS (the protocol used for sending tables back to clients).

Since it is built on top of the Entity Framework,i.e. the web service part is generated from a edmx data model, choosing to use ADO.NET Data Services is also choosing to use Entity Framework.

Comment: Are you 100% sure in your last paragraph? Can you elaborate or provide a link?

Comment: Here is one link: http://www.packtpub.com/article/data-access-with-ado-dot-net-data-services demonstrates that this is the way it is designed to be used. HOWEVER, you can use datasources that only support IQueriable.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc907912.aspx  It looks to me like one must write a lot more code for ADO.NET Services on top of IQueriable than on top of an edmx.

Comment: Ok, still there is another option, and you might want to use another ORM that produces IQueryable mappings...